# Instantiating a template function in all M * N combinations

Tags: c++, performance, templates

Imagine I have M methods that I want to time, along with N timing methods (let's call them *clock implementations*)<sup>1</sup>. The exact details aren't too important here, but I'm mentioning it so I can give a concrete example.

Now let's say I have a templatized timing method like so:

```
typedef void (bench_f)(uint64_t);

template <bench_f METHOD, typename CLOCK>
uint64_t time_method(size_t loop_count) {
  auto t0 = CLOCK::now();
  METHOD(loop_count);
  auto t1 = CLOCK::now();
  return t1 - t0;
}
```

Basically it brackets the call to `METHOD` with calls to `CLOCK::now()` and returns the difference. Note also that `METHOD` is not passed as a function pointer, but rather only as a template argument - so you get unique instantiations for *each* method, rather than one and then an indirect call through a pointer.

This works well for my case because both of the clock calls and the method under test are direct static calls (i.e., something like `call <function address>` at the assembly level).

Now I have N methods I want to test (perhaps 50) along with M clock methods (perhaps 5). I want to actually instantiate, at compile time, all M * N methods, so that I can call all the test methods with a specific clock implementation.

Now the "standard" way to do this would just to pass a function pointer (or class implementing a virtual function) for both the method under test and the clock implementation, at which point I'd only need a single `time_method` method and can create whatever combination I want at runtime. In this particular case, the performance impacts of the indirect calls are too much, so I want template instantiation and I am willing to pay the resulting binary bloat (e.g., M * N = 250 instantiated combinations with my numbers).

At runtime I want to get a list of N method combined with a particular clock, for example.

I am fine explicitly listing all N method and all M clocks, but I don't want to write out the M * N instantiations (DRY and all that).

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using the word *clock* pretty loosely here - some of the "clocks" may in fact measure aspects unrelated to time, such as heap memory use, or some application specific metric.

Comment: Are you going to merely iterate through them, or do you need a way to specify a particular arbitrary combination at runtime?

Comment: I will usually want to get a "slice" of the combinations, like "all N methods for 1 specific clock X". So basically what I'm looking for is a 2D M*N array of function pointers, with each pointer corresponding to a particular `time_method` instantiation for the corresponding `METHOD` and `CLOCK`. With that structure I can do whatever I want, although looping through one row/column would be the most common. Does that make sense @BenVoigt? Note that even though I want a subset, it's fine if all function pointers actually exist, etc.

Answer (score 8):

```
template<bench_f* ...> struct method_list {};
template<class...> struct clock_list {};

using time_method_t = uint64_t (*)(size_t);

template<bench_f Method, class...Clocks>
constexpr auto make_single_method_table()
    -> std::array<time_method_t, sizeof...(Clocks)> {
    return { time_method<Method, Clocks>... };
}

template<bench_f*... Methods, class... Clocks>
constexpr auto make_method_table(method_list<Methods...>, clock_list<Clocks...>)
    -> std::array<std::array<time_method_t, sizeof...(Clocks)>, sizeof...(Methods)> {
    return { make_single_method_table<Methods, Clocks...>()... };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make the code you must write linear in the sum of the number of options instead of their product, write template functions that remove one layer of option at a time.

e.g.

```
typedef uint64_t (*benchmark_runner)(size_t loop_count);

benchmark_runner all_runners[NMETHODS][NCLOCKS];

template <bench_f METHOD>
void fill_row(size_t bench_f_index)
{
    benchmark_runner* it = &all_runners[bench_f_index][0];
    *(it++) = &time_method<METHOD, FIRST_CLOCK>;
    *(it++) = &time_method<METHOD, SECOND_CLOCK>;
    *(it++) = &time_method<METHOD, THIRD_CLOCK>;
    *(it++) = &time_method<METHOD, LAST_CLOCK>;
}

void fill_all()
{
    int row = 0;
    fill_row<BENCH_A>(row++);
    fill_row<BENCH_B>(row++);
    ...
    fill_row<BENCH_Z>(row++);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a reasonable approach - to do the product at runtime. I was thinking there must be some template metaprogramming approach, but this doesn't seem terrible at all.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: You could do it with structures instead, applying the same remove-one-option-in-each-layer approach.  In the end after inlining, they're going to come out pretty much the same.

Comment: You could create a struct or class for your `method` and one for your `clock` and within those classes create a `static method` that would initialize and populate a `static map` for each type of `method` and `clock`. You could then use these `static maps` in your `templates` either it be a `function template` or a `class template`.

Comment: "to do the product at runtime" What do you mean exactly? Template instantiations are done at compile time. Calls to instantiated function templates are done at run time. Whatever you do, these two basic facts do not change.

Comment: @n.m. I mean that `fill_all()` (and, indirectly, `fill_row()`) are methods that I call at runtime and they build the the `all_runners` array. Of course the methods themselves already exist in the binary, but you still have to call the construction methods. Contrast with T.C. solution where the iteration happens at compile-time.